# How to get details of specific item/object from an array based on it's property id - React

Tags: reactjs

I am fetching some fake data from JSONPlaceholder API for prototyping purposes. I am rendering data in a HTML table for every item from fetched array. Initiali I am showing only few properties (id, name, username, email) on page view and many more of then came with JSON response. I would like to when clicking on specific item, in my case I am using method openDetails, to show the rest of that object data in html modal. I will implement modal from Material UI or Bootstrap so that isn't a problem, just don't know how to catch an Id of clicked item so I can find only that specific object from my state and show it's details in HTML modal.

This is the code:

```
class User extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: [],
      filteredUsers: [],
      s: ""
    };
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ users: response.data });
        this.setState({ filteredUsers: response.data });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
  componentWillReceiveProps = nextProps => {
    this.setState(
      {
        users: nextProps.users,
        filteredUsers: nextProps.users
      },
      () => this.filterList()
    );
  };
  searchList = e => {
    const s = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
    this.setState({ s }, () => this.filterList());
  };
  filterList = () => {
    let users = this.state.users;
    let s = this.state.s;

    users = users.filter(function(user) {
      return user.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(s) !== -1;
    });
    this.setState({ filteredUsers: users });
  };
  openDetails = id => {
    console.log(id);
  };

  renderTableData() {
    return this.state.filteredUsers.map((user, index) => {
      const { id, name, username, email } = user;
      return (
        <tr key={index}>
          <td>{id}</td>
          <td style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} onClick={this.openDetails(id)}>
            {name}
          </td>
          <td>{username}</td>
          <td>{email}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NavBar></NavBar>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search users"
          onChange={this.searchList}
          value={this.state.s}
        ></input>

        <table id="users">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>NAME</th>
              <th>USERNAME</th>
              <th>EMAIL</th>
            </tr>
            {this.renderTableData()}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: you are not getting console.log(id) right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use correct implementation of arrow function to support parameters.

```
<td style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} onClick={this.openDetails(id)}></td>

openDetails = id => e => {
  console.log(id)
}
```

It's better if you don't create inline arrow functions - `() => this.openDetails(id)` as its instance will be re-created on every re-render.

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: Thanks it helps, and now when I can send id of clicked item to my method in which I will find object with that specific id, how can I now pass that object data to my render method

Comment: Add that filtered object to state and access that state variable in render method.

Answer (score 0):

@tarzen...I am doing it like this but no luck, can't console log it out after I set it to state

```
openDetails = id => e => {
    let user = this.state.filteredUsers.find((user) => {
      return user.id === id;
    });
    this.setState({user: user})
    console.log(this.state.user)
  }
```

Here is the state

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: [],
      filteredUsers: [],
      s: "",
      user: {}
    };
  }
```

and finally html where that data should go:

```
<div className="modal-body">
</div>
```

Comment: Actually now I can console log it out but I late one object, first if I click object with Id of 1, I get empty object, and then click object with Id 2, I get first clicked obj, obj with Id 1, strange...why is this like so???